# Invalid record in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I have a problem with finding the problem with my create data method in seeds.rb. I use [faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to generate data. 
My code:

```
NAZWY_DNI = ['Poniedziałek', 'Wtorek', 'Środa', 'Czwartek', 'Piątek', 'Sobota', 'Niedziela']
60.times do
  WorkSchedule.create!(
    start_time: Faker::Time.forward(1, :morning).strftime("%H:%M"),
    end_time: Faker::Time.forward(1, :afternoon).strftime("%H:%M"),
    day_of_week: NAZWY_DNI[Random.new.rand(0..6)],
    person_id: Faker::Number.between(52, 112)
  )
end
  p "Created #{WorkSchedule.count} work schedules"
```

WorkSchedule table model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: work_schedules
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  start_time  :time             not null
#  end_time    :time             not null
#  day_of_week :string           not null
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  person_id   :integer
#
```

When I try `rake db:migrate`, there is an error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`. Do you know where I make mistake? Thanks in advance.

Full trace:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Nieprawidłowy rekord
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/home/lukas/Documents/aquapark/db/seeds.rb:84:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/lukas/Documents/aquapark/db/seeds.rb:83:in `times'
/home/lukas/Documents/aquapark/db/seeds.rb:83:in `<top (required)>'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/lukas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you also post the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what was a problem. In model work_schedule.rb I had this validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :day_of_week, scope: :person_id
```

When I commented this line, seed loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In your schema type of start_time/end_time columns is `time`. However, in your seeds you have `strftime("%H:%M")` call which converts time to string. Therefore, you should not call `strftime`.

Moreover, instead of `NAZWY_DNI[Random.new.rand(0..6)]` you can use `NAZWY_DNI.sample` that will randomly pick a day. Instead of `Faker::Number.between(52, 112)` just use `rand(52, 112)`.